# Cannot use namespace 'NavController'',NgZone',Google,as a type

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am new to ionic app developer, and I am facing this issue: when I open one Component, it is showing error messages, i.e, `cannot use namespace as type ionic(NgZone,NavController and googlePlus)`. Why am I getting this error message?

Here is my code:

```
export class HomePage {
  userProfile: any = null;
  zone: NgZone;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private googlePlus: GooglePlus) {
    this.zone = new NgZone({});
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( user => {
      this.zone.run( () => {
        if (user){
          this.userProfile = user;
        } else { 
          this.userProfile = null; 
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I applied the following changes to your question: fixed grammar, removed unnecessary details (it's okay that you're new; we don't need to see that in the question); improved formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to update your project's package. Please try with:

```
npm install / npm update
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Below code : ( The NgZone object can be created as below )

```
export class HomePage {
  userProfile: any = null;
  zone: NgZone;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private googlePlus: GooglePlus, private ngZone: NgZone) {
    this.zone = ngZone;
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( user => {
      this.zone.run( () => {
        if (user){
          this.userProfile = user;
        } else { 
          this.userProfile = null; 
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```